# C# "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: c#

I'm writing a server/client application. my server works great on local ip addresses and i am able to test all of its features using 127.0.0.1 as ip address and communicate with my server.
Today i used my public ip address as ip address in my server application and i configured my port forwarding and checks it with common tools on network and everyone says my port is open an actually i get port checker site packets on my server that shows everything works fine.
but when i want to connect from my client application that it is written in c#(also my server is in c#) i get exception in Socket.Connect function that code is below "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" :

```
 clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                Console.WriteLine("Connectiong to server");

                clientSocket.Connect("151.243.130.245", 1892);
```

and here is my listen method on my server :

```
  serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i)
                {
                    clients[i] = new Client();
                }

                serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1892));
                serverSocket.Listen(MAX_CLIENTS);
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
```

i have to mention that i tested port checker sites from my friend home and it did send a packet to my server.
also i have a wireless usb adaptor connected to my computer and i am connected with it to my mode.

i did search all the internet and everyone said that in this error common issues are you are not listening on that port or you are blocked by a firewall program but i have to say that i did both of them,it means i used -netstat -anb and it shows i am listening on port 1892 and also i configure firewall to let any connection goes through it but still no luck :(

any helps will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Switch off your firewall temporarily to make sure this is not the problem.

Comment: @BartFriederichs My firewall is not active i'm also on windows 10

Comment: @BartFriederichs if my firewall was on how can port checkers tools connect to my server?

Comment: @PeymanTahghighi this is most likely an networking issue, can you explain how your network is set up? Maybe it fails at some port forwarding on internal devices or alike.

Comment: @Vulpex what you mean by "how your network setup?" i'm using d-lin 2640T as router that i use as i wireless device and connect to it using d-link wireless usb adaptor,is that enough?

Comment: @bommelding i have same idea as you,i think i should add something like 192.168.1.2 at the end of my public ip address to direct it to my computer. is there any way to do that?

Comment: @PeymanTahghighi how is the server connected to what, how is the client connected to what. What type of devices are inbetween, that kind of stuff

Comment: You can't add an IP to an IP. That is what port-forwarding is for. You said you had that covered. Now you have to elaborate on it.

Comment: @Vulpex both server and client are on my own computer.

Comment: @bommelding correct. and i have no idea what to do :(

Comment: so they have the same ip address, both connected via WIFI, to a single router. Using the loopback address works but not the internal ip address. That sounds like firewall or portforwarding. Have you double checked that the correct firewall and portforwarding rules are set?

Comment: @Vulpex in port forwarding part i am pretty sure it is working fine i used all of online tools and they say it is open and ready to use.
But in firewall setting i am not so sure i alow my client and server through firewall but still not working. is there anything more that should i check?

Comment: @PeymanTahghighi have you tried to connect with the software from outside of your home network? Not just port checking but let the application run from an different device from an different network. [more about this here](https://superuser.com/questions/307820/how-do-i-properly-test-whether-my-port-forwarding-works?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @Vulpex yes and still not working!

Comment: That IP address is owned by Aria Shatel Company Ltd, located in Tehran, Iran.  Your ISP, I imagine.  No, they are not going to be happy about you trying to use that port.  You'll have to do this on a local network, typically 192.168.1.something

Comment: "all of online tools and they say it is open" does not prove that "port forwarding part i am pretty sure it is working". I am still not sure that you know what port forwarding is.